# Google reCAPTCHA invisible - Where does it get it's information?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, invisible-recaptcha

So I'm coding a page with Laravel and the user needs to go through five pages until he gets to a submit button to publish something. The last page contains only three checkboxes. The user has to check at least two of three. How should google know that the user is a bot? I'm curious how this work. Because only at the very end I'm using reCAPTCHA invisible .

Besides Google has written you should include the script to use it, but not when exactly:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

I'm using it only on the very last page. The page where the user needs to be checked. Is this enough? Or should it be on every single page of mine, in order to track the movement of the user?

Comment: `How should google know that the user is a bot?` Nobody outside of Google really knows how it works. It's kind of Google's classified technology. Apparently, they track and monitor the user's actions and movements before clicking "I'm not a robot", and check whether it's a human-esque behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be fine using it on the last page only -
 it should work even if the action is a single button press. 
 As for how it works, this article gives some insight: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/03/googles-recaptcha-announces-invisible-background-captchas/

Apparently it uses "a combination of machine learning and advanced risk analysis that adapts to new and emerging threats."  Who knows how many features their model uses...mouse movement, time of captcha render to execution, IP address, and User Agent are probably some of those variables.  Anyways, if the algorithm determines the user is suspicious they'll still receive a popup with the captcha challenge.